# NSIS Uninstaller wont unistall files that werent in the same directory as the .nsi during compile

Tags: nsis

I have been trying to add in an Uninstall only installed files function into my NSIS installer using the Uninstall only installed files tutorial that can be found [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Uninstall_only_installed_files)

The example works fine when I only add files to the installer that are in the same directory as the .nsi source file. For example adding a file using this command:

```
${File} "file.txt"
```

The file file.txt is installed and can also deleted when you run the uninstaller. However if I place file.txt into a subdirectory called Files and use the command:

```
 ${File} "Files\file.txt"
```

The file.txt file will be installed correctly, but when I run the uninstaller it wont be deleted.

Am I missing something obvious with NSIS here?

Answer (score 0):

May be one of the following two reasons:-

1. In your `$InstDir` `Files\File.txt` is just included like `$InstDir\File.txt` whereas Uninstaller is trying to Delete `$InstDir\Files\File.txt`.
2. In your `$InstDir` `Files\File.txt` is included like `$InstDir\Files\File.txt` But your Uninstaller is trying to Delete `$InstDir\File.txt`.